# .c file in Xcode Project how to use / implement?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, serial-port

The Xcode project I am working on contains a `.c` file which I sourced from [this tutorial](http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial)  I want to open the serial port and listen for data coming in, so I created a method in a `.m` file which I named `addRFID`.  How would I go about opening the port and listen for data coming in on the RX line within the `.m` file?

Comment: What is the `m` file?  Mathematica?  Matlab?  Maple?

Comment: the `.h` is the header file, and the `.m` is the implementation file.

Comment: I've never heard of putting C code in a `.m` file before.  Why would you do that?  Also, I'm not sure this question has enough information for anyone to answer it.

Comment: So you want to call code from an ordinary C source file from Objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

c files can be included in your project in exactly the same way as .m files. My suggestion is to create a header file for that .c (i.e. make a .h in which you declare all of the functions and variables, constants, etc), and import that in your .m, then use the functions as you see fit, calling them directly from inside object methods.

Then simply make sure that the .c file is included in your target so that it gets compiled and things should work great.

To summarize:

1. Don't directly import your .c file
2. Include the .c file in your target for compilation
3. make a .h file declaring all the interface, which you do directly import.